# How to use Python 3.7 Code inside Custom Module for Magetno 2?

Tags: magento2, module

I need to create a custom Module for Magento-2 which also has a Python code.

**so how to integrate python + Magento into Custom Module.**

I mean to say that Magento 2, Custom Module and Python Code need to run on the same platform.

Comment: I believe that no one did it previously because it mostly does not  make sense.

Comment: Dear sir now Days Python is more popular in every area of Technology so it's a New for Magento. If we did it successful then we make Wide E-commerce Network with Magento + Python. So pls help.

Comment: how to integration  Python and Magento 2  ???

Comment: check this link if it's relevant to you 
**https://devdocs.magento.com/mbi/docs/libraries.html**

Comment: Provided python is available on the same machine that runs the php code you might be able to use exec - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php

Comment: Check this link https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.xmlrpc.php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Build RPC server on python and call it from Magento Module

Comment: Agree with this answer. we had almost same situation in our project where we need to process some data vai NODEJS. so we have created API in NODEJS and used those API's in Magento custom module and all worked smoothly.